# Solving third order quadratic nonlinear DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to solve the following nonlinear DE using a numerical integration algorithm (like runge-kutta)

$a_0\dddot{x}^2+a_1\dddot{x}+m\ddot{x}+c\dot{x}+kx=0$

I cannot isolate $\dddot{x}$, how can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Paulo.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the equation to a first-order system by letting: $y_1=x$, $y'_1=x'=y_2$ and $y'_2=x''=y_3$ and $y'_3=x'''$. This leads to the following system
$$y'_1=y_2$$
$$y'_2=y_3$$
$$a_0(y'_3)^2+a_1y'_3+my_3+cy_2+ky_1=0$$ (quadratic equation in $y'_3$) or solving this for $y'_3$ we get
$$y'_3=\frac{-a_1 \pm\sqrt{a^2_1-4a_0(my_3+cy_2+ky_1)}}{2a_0}.$$
Thus the third derivative is isolated and you can use your iteration on this system.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi, excuse my ignorance, but when I tried to implement these equations I came to a question of which root I should use? (since there are two)